# How to move custom objects from list to list?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Recently I got a problem which I do not know how to solve.

I got 2 different `ArrayLists`, each one is in another `Activity`.
My goal is to move Symptoms (custom objects) from one list to another, I thought I could use `SharedPreferences` in order to move the data, however it doesn't work in case I want to move more than one Symptom.

At the sending screen;

```
            //My attempt :
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("syms", 0);
Editor edit=sp.edit();
edit.putString("SYM_Name", mySym.get(position).name);
edit.putString("SYM_Details", mySym.get(position).details);
edit.commit();
```

At the receiving screen:

> SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("syms", 0);
>
> allSym.add( new Symptom (sp.getString("SYM_Name", null) , sp.getString("SYM_Details", null)));

I hope you guys could please help me here,

Thanks in advance;

Yaniv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting activity Two from activity One. then you can pass objects through Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("symptoms", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Since ArrayList is Serializable you can use in putExtra().

Comment: I have another screen that connecting between them.

Comment: Then you can pass this object from this Middle Activity to ActivityTwo. Just getIntent().getExtra("symptoms") in Middle Activity and put into Intent while starting ActivityTwo.

Comment: I eventually do it, in case I won't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could also try passing the data via an Intent.

Comment: I thought about it, but after I'm running the code I do not want to move to the other screen right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to parse them into Json and then you can put the string in SharedPrefs, get it back out parse them back.

[Refer to this tutorial for more.](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)

Comment: Could you please give more details about these "Json" and "Gson"?